# scan a product then navigate to another component with nativescript-vue

Tags: vuejs2, fetch, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Im making a simple application with nativescript-vue, on the home page i have a button that launch the scanner so i can scan a product. Here is my home page :

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">

   <StackLayout class="hello-world">
     <Button @tap="scan" text="Scan a product"/>
   </StackLayout>

  </Page>
</template>

<script>
const BarcodeScanner = require("nativescript- 
barcodescanner").BarcodeScanner;
import Display from "./Display";
export default {
data() {
  return {
    text: ""
  };
},
methods: {
scan: function() {
  var barcodescanner = new BarcodeScanner();
  barcodescanner
    .scan({
      // formats: "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // Pass in of you want to restrict scanning to certain types
      cancelLabel: "EXIT. Also, try the volume buttons!", // iOS only, default 'Close'
      cancelLabelBackgroundColor: "#333333", // iOS only, default '#000000' (black)
      message: "Use the volume buttons for extra light", // Android only, default is 'Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it.'
      showFlipCameraButton: true, // default false
      preferFrontCamera: false, // default false
      showTorchButton: true, // default false
      beepOnScan: true, // Play or Suppress beep on scan (default true)
      torchOn: false, // launch with the flashlight on (default false)
      closeCallback: function() {
        console.log("Scanner closed");
      }, // invoked when the scanner was closed (success or abort)
      resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android only, default 1500 (ms), set to 0 to disable echoing the scanned text
      // orientation: "landscape", // Android only, optionally lock the orientation to either "portrait" or "landscape"
      openSettingsIfPermissionWasPreviouslyDenied: true // On iOS you can send the user to the settings app if access was previously denied
    })
    .then(
      function(result) {
        console.log("Scan format : " + result.format);
        console.log("Scan text :   " + result.text);
        this.text = result.text.trim();
         this.$navigateTo(Display, {context: {propsData: {"code":  this.text }}});

      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("No scan: " + error);
      }
    );
  }
}
};
</script>
```

Once the scan is finish i want to navigate to my other component "Display"  where i want to use the text scanned before to make a fetch request to my api and have some product information about it, here is my display component :

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">
    <ActionBar class="action-bar" title="Results"/>

   <StackLayout>
     <Label v-if="posts.product_name" :text="posts.product_name" />
     <Image :src="posts.image_thumb_url" stretch="none" />
     <Label :text="posts.ingredients_text_fr" class="list-group-item-text" textWrap="true"></Label>
   </StackLayout>

  </Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    code: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
   }
  },
data() {
  return {
    posts: [],
  };
},
methods: {},
beforeCreate() {
  fetch(
  `my-api.com/product/${this.code}.json`
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
   this.posts = data.product;
      });
  }
};
 </script>
```

But here i have a problem i don't know how to make the call to my api and when (mounted, beforeMounted....). Because my "display" component seems already mounted at the same time than my "home"  component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set a data value to true, and have your Display component use a v-if directive.  That will also mount it.

```
data:{
   showDisplay: false
}

<Display v-if ='showDisplay' />

someAsyncMethod().then(result => {
   // do init here
   this.showDisplay = true
}
```

Comment: But i would prefer to navigate to a new frame to make an appropriate design (and it seems that i have to with nativescript-vue)

Comment: Then put the v-if in your template tag and navigate to it after setting the flag. That will delay your mount.

Comment: So v-if evaluates to false and your component is still mounted?

Comment: v-if on the template tag doesn't seem to be interpreted at all. so yes it is mounted anyway.

Comment: So if you put a template tag around your product element and use v-if='false', it still gets mounted?

Comment: it works on the "page" tag  which is the first child after the template one but as my display is in another file i will try to transmit a boolean to it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not Use `function() {}` use Arrow function(`=>`) instead. with Arrow functions context of `this` won't change on the other hand context of  `this` will change based on the calling context if you use `function() {}`.